# Gerrit - how to extend the UI via JS API

Tags: javascript, jquery, gerrit

I fairly new to this topic and I need to extend the Gerrit UI,lets say add some button on the toop.Currenlty I dont know how to start,please assist which steps I should use to do that ?

This is the JS API

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/js-api.html

I download the war 2.1 from this link

https://gerrit-releases.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

But not sure how to start....

Comment: You downloaded 2.10, I hope (this is not 2.1.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [cookbook plugin](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/cookbook-plugin/), which shows some of the typical extension points for Gerrit.

I think the [HelloTopMenu](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/cookbook-plugin/+/master/src/main/java/com/googlesource/gerrit/plugins/cookbook/HelloTopMenu.java) is what you're searching for.